# Client Side to Server Side Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js application and I have a public/somehting.js file that is client side and then I have a controller file controllers/something.js and models/something.js that does the DB connection.

How do I go from the public directory and access the server side information any ideas

my **model/features.js**

```
exports.getFeatureClass = function(Sequelize, sequelize) {
  sequelize.define("Feature", {
    project_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
  });
};
```

my **public/featurepane.js**

```
var FeaturePane = function FeaturePane(scope) {
  console.log("hi");
  //how to I access Db
};
```

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

node isn't a "plug in"/CGI interpreter like PHP is, you need to actually set up a server in node and have that serve any requests and process server side JS.

There are several frameworks that does this for you, the most used one is probably [express](http://expressjs.com/).